# python+gae compatible web ui toolkit with ajax but degrades gracefully when there is no js?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am searching for a web toolkit that is

- Python compatible
- social/db/wiki like
- google-appengine compatible

  - has built in pagination
  - handles 'relationships' between entities
- uses ajax

  - modal dialogs
  - but degrades very gracefully on browsers that dont have js
- good ui decisions that make it gracefully degrade even on mobile, text and braille/speech interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

[Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).

They aren't exactly a unified framework, but I don't really know of any frameworks comprised of Python and JS together that fit your description.

There are also gigantic communities behind both Django and JQuery, which will help you immensely should you ever encounter any problems.

Django is more or less GAE compatible, and is getting more compatible every day, particularly with the [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) project.

JQuery is probably the most used JS library out there, with tons of documentation and third-party plugins to accomplish basically anything you may want to do.